# Let $f(x,y)=5xy^2−5x^3.$ Find the rate of decrease in the direction of $(1,3)$.

Tags: calculus

> Let $f(x,y)=5xy^2−5x^3.$ Find the rate of decrease in the direction of $(1,3)$.

So first I took the gradient at the point of this function, which is $(5y^2-15x^2)i+(10xy)j,$ and replaced it with $(1,3)$. I get $\langle 30,30 \rangle$. And since it is decreasing, I put them in the negative direction, so $\langle -30,-30\rangle$ is decreasing faster at that point. Now, I took the magnitude of $\langle 30,30 \rangle$, which is $\sqrt{30^2 + 30^2} = 42.426$. This is the rate of increase, so the rate of decrease should be $-42.426$.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, please check to see whether I have edited your work correctly.  You did not state what you found for the gradient in the first sentence, so I left that blank.

Answer (score 2):

You've found the rate of greatest decrease, not the decrease in the direction of $(1,3).$  This is a directional derivative problem.  The answer is the projection of the gradient on the direction vector.

Comment: Moreover, it’s the rate of greatest decrease at $(1,3)$, but the problem doesn’t specify any particular point at which to compute the rate.